# How to set a value for wait() in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, wait, casperjs

This is my complete code .. What I want is that the casper.wait have a random waiting time of 1-3 seconds. If I put " casper.wait (1000, function () {" entering a numeric value , if it works, however casper.wait (time , function () { entering the variable value is not working.

```js
casper.then(function() {

  this.echo('Looking random number.....');
  rrandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);

  if (rrandom == 1) {
    time = 1000
  }
  if (rrandom == 2) {
    time = 2000
  }
  if (rrandom == 3) {
    time = 3000
  }
});

casper.wait(time, function() {
  this.echo('result');
});


casper.run();
```

Comment: This will work as you would expect. I suspect this is a problem with your surrounding code. Can you give a full and minimal example?

Comment: does not work, I think wait () is not compatible with variable values ?? only numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample ***rrandom*** sometimes will be equal to 0, because `Math.round()` rounds values of < 0.49 to zero. Thus ***time*** will be sometimes undefined, breaking the script.

I would suggest something like this:

```
var time;
casper.then(function() {
  var maxSecTimeout = 3;

  this.echo('Pausing for ' + maxSecTimeout + ' seconds');

  time = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxSecTimeout) * 1000;  
});

casper.wait(time, function() {
  this.echo('result');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: does not work, I think wait () is not compatible with variable values ?? only numbers

Comment: `time` is a local variable and not available in the following `wait` call, because a global `time` variable is referenced.

Comment: if this already in use , please tell me how I can gratificarle . Thank you so much